# Marking properties as fillable when using Laravel relationship functions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

I have a `Team` model which can have many `Site` models attached, and has a `createSite` function to add sites:

```php
public function createSite($domain) {
    $site = new Site(['domain' => $domain]);
    return $this->sites()->save($site);
}
```

Running this fails, as `domain` is not `fillable`. While easily fixed, I've read the [docs on Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) and am trying to minimise which fields are fillable.

What's best practice here? Should I use `$fillable` or explicitly assign these properties (ie `$site->domain = $domain`)?

Comment: Apparently the $domain is being supplied to create a new website and doesn't seem to be very sensitive info. So allowing mass assignment should not be any issue. However if you want to imbibe a habit of exposing the minimum possible surface area for mass assignment vulnerability you can go with `$site = new Site(); $site->domain = $domain; $site->save();`

Comment: I personally explicitly set the fillable attributes on each model. That way I can do things like `FooBar::create($request->only(['name', 'email', 'age']));` as opposed to setting each attribute when using `new Model()`;

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I think the intent here is to expose minimum attributes in the `$fillable` array and for any other attributes define functions/methods on Model to circumvent the mass assignment exception.

Comment: I don't see any difference in whitelisting model attributes vs manually setting each one, the same data is populating the model instance either way. That being said, you can also temporarily remove any mass assignment restrictions by calling `Site::unguard();` and `Site::reguard();` before and after mass assignment, respectively.

Comment: Attributes whitelisted/exposed in `$fillable` can be filled by guess work also (just for argument sake) while manually setting any attribute from within a Model or class still protects against mass assignment.

Comment: The guess work argument is a bit of a stretch, imo. With CSRF protections, form validation, user authentication, etc. all in place, an attacker would still need to have a good idea of your db schema to pose any kind of real threat by guessing fields and values. On top of that, I use `$request->only()` to selectively pick the request data to use when mass assigning. I think someone would have to be _incredibly_ careless to have it be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can also protected $guarded = [] it is same as fillable but its functionality is opposite to the fillable you can read about it on the official web.